# Is there any method to put data into JS function?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the function which is getting two values from firebase.I want a progress-bar which will work as soon as any data from the firebase is retrieved.

```
function toggleVideoState(fvalues, fthreshold) {
  const threshold = window.document.getElementsByClassName("threshold");
  var progressBar = window.document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
  var progressContainer = window.document.getElementsByClassName( "progress-container");
  var live=window.document.getElementsByClassName("live");
  let thresholdValue, value;
```

But there is a problem that if i am getting the values from firebase by the device which means no input value from the user so this addEventListener function is not working. I want an alternate method of it.

```
document.addEventListener("change", e => {
if (e.target.className.indexOf('threshold') > -1) {
  setProgressBarValues(e.target, 'threshold');
} else if (e.target.className.indexOf('live') > -1) {
  setProgressBarValues(e.target, 'live');

}
});
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
var headdiv = document.getElementById('headdiv');
var elem = document.querySelector('#mycontainer');
var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = 'mycontainer' + i;
headdiv.appendChild(clone);
}
function setProgressBarValues(changedElement, changedElemName) {
var parent = changedElement.parentElement;
var thresholdValue, liveValue;

if (changedElemName === 'threshold') {
    thresholdValue = changedElement.value;
    liveValue = parent.querySelector('.live').value;
} else if (changedElemName === 'live') {
   thresholdValue = parent.querySelector('.threshold').value;
   liveValue = changedElement.value;
}

if (thresholdValue && liveValue) {
    const progressBar = parent.querySelector(".progress-bar");
    const progressContainer = parent.querySelector(".progress-container");

    let percentValue = Math.floor((liveValue / (2 * thresholdValue)) * 100);
    let percentMargin = Math.floor((25 * liveValue) / 100);
    console.log(percentValue, percentMargin);
    if (liveValue < 100) {
       progressBar.style.height = `calc(${liveValue}% - ${percentMargin}px)`;
    } else if (liveValue => 100) {
       progressBar.style.height = `calc(100% - 25px)`;
    } else {
      progressBar.style.height = `0px`;
    }
    if (percentValue < 50) {
      progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      progressContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
    } else {
      progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      progressContainer.style.borderColor = "green";
    }
}
}

}
```

html code:

These are the two input boxes which i have to remove so that instead of userinput the values will be get from the firebase.

```
<input
      class="threshold"
      placeholder="threshold value"
      type="text"
      style="width: 120px; margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 0%; padding: 10px;" 
      />

    <input
      class="live"
      placeholder="live value"
      type="text"
      style="width: 120px; margin-bottom: 20px;padding: 10px;"
     />
```

In short i want to make a realtime progress-bar which get its values from firebase

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is the case, you had two input fields, and using the values of those your function works properly. But now you are getting values from firebase and you want your function should work the same way with values of firebase. Am I correct?

Comment: yes  you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems like you were playing with multiple values at first, but now you have only one set of values.

So In that case you should something like this

```
function toggleVideoState(fvalues, fthreshold) {
   const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
   const progressContainer = document.querySelector(".progress-container");

   let percentValue = Math.floor((fvalues/ (2 * fthreshold)) * 100);
   let percentMargin = Math.floor((25 * fvalues) / 100);
   console.log(percentValue, percentMargin);
   if (fvalues < 100) {
      progressBar.style.height = `calc(${fvalues}% - ${percentMargin}px)`;
   } else if (fvalues=> 100) {
      progressBar.style.height = `calc(100% - 25px)`;
   } else {
      progressBar.style.height = `0px`;
   }
   if (percentValue < 50) {
     progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     progressContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
   } else {
     progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     progressContainer.style.borderColor = "green";
   }
 }
```

Or specify in the question, the dummy inputs you get in your function `toggleVideoState`. Also html structure of your progress bars.

Comment: Thanks once again Kenny ! its working now .Yeah the inputs values are just the number between 1-100 ..Thankyou so much!!